# Evernot Android-Job: принцип работы

Tags: android

Ребята, не могу понять принцип работы данной библиотеки.

У меня в приложении есть сервис,который по таймеру выполняет определённую задачу, но сервис нестабильная вещь, она то работает, то при очищении памяти может не работать.

Задавал вопрос здесь, все советуют работать с библиотекой Android-Job.

Весь интернет обрыл, но не могу понять принцип работы данной библиотеки. Как она работает? При закрытии приложения она будет работать?Она аналогична Service? Как сделать периодичное выполнение определённого задания, которое будет работать постоянно,не важно,закрыто приложение или открыто и т.д..

Помогите!

Вот код моего Service:

```
package com.hodite.com.shcherbuk;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Headers;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;

public class MyService extends Service implements Constants {

    NotificationManager nm;
    SharedPreferences sp;


    public MyService() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        sp = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    }


    public void myTimer(){
        Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
            @Override
            public void run() {
                push();
            }
        }, 3L*1000, 3L * 1000); // 600 миллисекунд до первого запуска,1800
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // onTaskRemoved(intent);

        myTimer();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AutoStart.class);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AutoStart.class);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void push() {
        try {
            new asynchronousGet().run();
            Log.i("Good","good");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Eror","errorororor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void pushText(String str1,String str2){
        //String url="http://"+str2;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify((str1+str2).hashCode(),notification);
    }


    /*---------------------КЛАСС ДЛЯ СЧИТЫВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА ИЗ ФАЙЛА-----------*/
    public class asynchronousGet {
        private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        public void run() throws Exception {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL_TEXT_TXT)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful())
                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        }
                        // Log.i("Good",responseBody.string());
                        // System.out.print(responseBody.string().toString());//СЧИТАННЫЙ ТЕКСТ
                        String string=responseBody.string();
                        int count=0;
                        String[] strings=new String[2];
                        for (String str : string.split("\n")) {
                            Log.i("str",str);
                            strings[count]=str;
                            count++;
                        }
                        String s1;
                        String s2;
                            s1=sp.getString(notif_text, "notif_text");
                            Log.i("s1",s1);
                            s2=sp.getString(notif_url, "notif_url");
                            Log.i("s2",s2);
                            if(!(s1.equals(strings[0]) && s2.equals(strings[1]))){
                                /*Отправляем строки в уведомление*/
                                pushText(strings[0],strings[1]);

                                /*Сохранение переменных в SharedPreference*/
                                SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                                e.putString(notif_text, strings[0]);
                                e.putString(notif_url, strings[1]);
                                e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                            }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    /**------------------------------------------------------------------**/
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```